# Calculated readonly Member as Calculated Column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I Have the following class and want to be able to query it using such a Linq Query `dbContext.Example.Where(e=> e.IsBetween);`

```
public class Example {
  public DateTime Start {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
  public bool IsBetween => DateTime.Now >= Start && DateTime.Now <= End ;
}
```

However this results in an "The LINQ expression [...] could not be translated. Either rewrite [...] or switch to client evaluation" error at runtime.

Is there any way for me to link the readonly Property `IsBetween` to a CalculatedColumn in the db?

Comment: I have tried  in asp.net core 3.1 `List<Example> ls = new List<Example>();
            ls.Where(x => x.IsBetween);` its not giving me any compilation error

Comment: It does not throw a compilation but a runtime error, should have specified that, sorry!

Comment: @viveknuna what you tried is just LINQ-to-Objects, not Entity Framework. There's no way to convert any arbitrary function to SQL short of decompiling the code. When you write an EF query with LINQ you use *expressions*, not lambdas or functions

Comment: @Torui what you tried is impossible - there's no way to translate functions to SQL. LINQ to EF or NHibernate works with *expressions* which get translated to SQL if possible. The error clearly says you *can't* convert that function to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that EF can't transform you custom method (property getter) into SQL. If you have/want to map `IsBetween` to computed column in db you should do it [accordingly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations). Something like this(have not checked validity of SQL):

```
public class Example {
  public DateTime Start {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
  public bool IsBetween {get; set;} ;
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // your setup ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Example>()
        .Property(p => p.IsBetween)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("getdate() >= Start AND getdate() <= END");
}
```

If you want `IsBetween` to exist just in code you will need to use [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), or example:

```
public class Example {
  public DateTime Start {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
  public bool IsBetween => _func(this) ; 
  public static readonly Expression<Func<Example, bool>> IsBetweenExpr = e => 
      DateTime.Now >= e.Start && DateTime.Now <= e.End;
  private static readonly Func<Example, bool> _func = _expr.Compile();
}

dbContext.Example.Where(Example.IsBetweenExpr) ....;
```

Comment: This throws an `InvalidOperationException` because `IsBetween`, as a calculated Property, lacks a backing field

Comment: I am sure you will get the below exception.

> The entity type 'Example' requires a primary key to be defined. If you
> intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

Comment: @Torui, yes, see updated post, obviously you should change `IsBetween` to auto-implemented property.

Comment: @viveknuna we can safely assume the OP posted a minimal example, not the entire class. Whether that minimal example has a key or not a) isn't related to calculated properties and b) the OP would have encountered such an exception already. So `Example` either has a key or is marked keyless already